# Retrieving a JOIN array from MySql

Tags: php, mysql, join, mysqli

I'm pulling a joined query from the DB using the following code:

```
$query = 'SELECT `profiles`.`city`, `users`.`first_name`, `users`.`last_name`'
         . ' FROM profiles, users'
         . ' WHERE ((`profiles`.`user_id` = 3) AND (`users`.`user_id` = 3))'
         . ' LIMIT 1';
  $result = $connection -> query($query);

  $arr = $result -> fetch_array();

  $feedback = $arr;

  $result -> close();
  return $feedback;
```

This isn't my final code, this is just preliminary to test my join.

The query seems to work fine, it pulls the single row of information I need but I noticed that when I `var_dump` it, it's put the array into 2 different indexes, a numerical index and an index of the name of the db field.  Here's what the `var_dump` looks like:

```
array(6) { [0]=> string(4) "Reno" ["city"]=> string(4) "Reno" [1]=> string(4) "John" ["first_name"]=> string(4) "John" [2]=> string(3) "Doe" ["last_name"]=> string(3) "Doe" }
```

This is effectively doubling the size of my query result.  For a single row this won't be that big of a deal but if/when I begin to use this same method to draw multiple records, doubling the size of the result can be costly.

I've tried to do a `foreach` loop:

```
foreach ($arr as $key=>$value) {
   $feedback[$key] = $value;
}
```

but it leaves me with the same result.  Am I doing something wrong and if so, how do I correct it or is this normal?

Thanks for you help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default *result type* for `mysqli_result::fetch_array()` is `MYSQLI_BOTH` meaning you get both named and numeric result array indices (see http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-array.php).

Try using [`fetch_assoc()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-assoc.php) instead.

Comment: "The default MySQL fetch mode" --- uhm, what?

Comment: Awesome!  Thanks for the SUPER fast reply!  Works perfect.  I'll accept it as soon as it allows me! I put in `fetch_array(MSQL_ASSOC)` and it work

Comment: @zerkms Can you tell I prefer PDO (where it's called *fetch mode*)? I've corrected the semantics

Comment: @Phil: I pointed on `mysql` vs `mysqli` actually ;-) `mysql` itself doesn't have any fetch mode or result type defaults

Comment: @zerkms Sure it does. See [`mysql_fetch_array()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-array.php), second arg `int $result_type = MYSQL_BOTH`

Comment: @Phil: `MySQL` - is a database management server. You even use the same capitalization like they have on http://mysql.com ;-) That is why in documentation `mysql extension` term is used.

Comment: @Phil: yes I am ;-) +1 anyway

Answer (score 0):

To reduce the size, you'll want to look at the second optional argument to mysql_fetch_array.  This is documented here:

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-array.php

You can specify if you just want numerical-indexes or associative arrays.

Answer (score 0):

If you use fetch row (http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-row.php) you will fetch without the names. I think this is what you are looking for, right?

EDIT: This also apllied to mysql, but the function is mysql_fetch_row($result) instead of mysqli

Comment: Thanks but no, I should have specified, though Phil hit it on the head; I want to return the `_ASSOC` part of the result - will be easier for me to know where my value's are at.